# Remove the verb from the Facebook Like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

On this page we can customize the verb associated with the Facebook like button. 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Just wondering if we can totally remove the verb (Like or Recommend) and instead just use the thumb icon. Would that be against Facebook terms of services?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not read the terms of service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no option to remove the verb from the Like Button, and as you said, altering the button outside the scope of the provided options is a violation of Facebook policy.